# Cannot find an attribute ID for an element RequestorID for added SOAP (wsdl) Generated serialized XML

Tags: xml, sabre

I am using sabre SOAP Bargain Max finder api. i am missing "ID" Attribute in RequestorID node. In response it return an error of Schema Not Valid. and shows the error "cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'ID' must appear on element 'RequestorID , Code:INVALIDREQ"
please Guide me what to do with wsdl and generated schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.9.2" ResponseType="Return">
      <POS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <Source PseudoCityCode="IPCC">
          <RequestorID Type="1" Instance="1" ID_Context="1">
            <CompanyName CompanyShortName="NT" Code="NT">NT</CompanyName>
          </RequestorID>
        </Source>
      </POS>
      <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <DepartureDateTime>2016-04-01T11:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="MOW" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LAX" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <SegmentType />
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <ArrivalDateTime>2016-04-15T11:00:00</ArrivalDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="LAX" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MOW" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <SegmentType />
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <TravelPreferences ValidInterlineTicket="true" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <CabinPref />
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <TripType />
          <LongConnectTime />
          <ExcludeCallDirectCarriers />
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </TravelPreferences>
      <TravelerInfoSummary xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
          <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
        </AirTravelerAvail>
      </TravelerInfoSummary>
      <TPA_Extensions xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <IntelliSellTransaction>
          <RequestType Name="50ITINS">50ITINS</RequestType>
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
      </TPA_Extensions>
    </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

Comment: I'm also getting this after updating to the 1.9.x version of BFM (Was ok in earlier versions) I can 'fix' it by adding an '[XmlAttribute("ID")]' on the generated RequestorID.ID_Context property (.Net) but obv. that's not a good solution.

Comment: i did changes in schema and proxy classes but its not working in .Net.. can you guide me on that way..

Comment: In class UniqueID_Type


/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("ID")]
public string ID_Context {
    get {
        return this.iD_ContextField;
    }
    set {
        this.iD_ContextField = value;
    }
}

Is what got me started, but It's not a solution I'd recommend: Your changes will get lost if you regenerate / update the proxy. -- Sorry about the formatting!

Comment: thank you so much for your precious commnets... instead of using proxy classes i used xml request response, through which i resolve this issue but now one error is there which is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109904/cvc-elt-1-a-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-ota-airlowfaresearchrq
I followed the answer but the issue remain the same.. 
can you help me please??